# Windows 7 network sees one machine but not the other

Tags: wireless-networking

Running a wireless network with a BT hub.  One laptop and one desktop both running W7 Home Premium.  Set up as Home computers and created a Homegroup on the desktop.  Used the password to join the laptop to the Homegroup and it shows proper connections and accessibilty exactly as expected.

Now the weird bit - the desktop says no other computers are available in the Homegroup!  The laptop permissions have been set and even the C: drive has been set to 'shared'.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Allot of antivirus programs and firewall programs are KNOWN to block this home-group feature. Make sure all antivirus/firewall programs are allowing this feature. If this computer is part of a domain, it needs to be logged in as a user that has administrative rights. Let me know what firewall / antivirus programs you have on both computer to help further troubleshoot this.